# Where are the failure details?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

Since `jasmine@2.5.0`, the CLI has changed and I can't find the new failure messages.

When I run jasmine, it tells me

`npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.`

But there is no "above". Where are the details?